# When you look at this try not to get dizzy!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

All parts of the puzzle are located below:

```
|v|g|u|a|b|c|e|b|-8
|j|g|u|r|a|l|b|o|-7
|y|f|b|h|v|s|h|y|-6
|y|v|l|v|u|h|f|r|-5
|m|u|r|u|b|p|b|z|-4
|m|g|e|n|j|n|y|o|-3
|h|q|n|r|e|a|i|l|-2
|c|f|v|u|g|q|r|r|-1
 | | | | | | | | 
 n o p q r s t u
```

Comment: Well, I suppose it's a hint that this is not a "code puzzle"?

Comment: It is sort of but once you solve it I think u will understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this puzzle, note that:

> The letters n-u (written along the bottom of the puzzle) are actually the letters a-h with the rot-13 Caesar shift applied. These would be the first 8 letters of the alphabet, to match the first 8 numbers written up the side of the grid.
>
>  So intuition suggests that perhaps we should apply the cipher to the entire grid.

Once we do that...

> ...we get a grid of new letters within which some real words can be spotted, e.g. 'solve' downwards in the seventh column, and the beginnings of 'puzzl(e)' upwards in the first. In fact, if we start on the 'h' in the fifth row and fourth column, we can read a message spiralling out of the grid (punctuation added):
>
>  **Hi, how are you? If u can read this then you solved this puzzll (sic) with no problem. Bye!**
>
>  [image: The message revealed]
>
>  And thus it seems the puzzle is solved!

A note on the title:

> This makes reference to the spiralling nature of the hidden message - it is easy to get dizzy when you are going around and around!